# How to fix an error while loading certificates in Visual Studio for iOS provisioning profiles?

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, provisioning-profile

The setup is: Visual Studio 2019 + Xamarin (last available updates)

The error occurs in Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts > View Details...

> "There was an error while loading your certificates: Could not load
> file or assemble 'Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, ..."

[image: First error window]

[image: Second error window]

I tried to remove and add again Apple Account in VS and got the same error with Polly

[image]

Comment: Hi , you can have a check with the Apple Account whether be invalid or expired .

Comment: The account is okay, it loads in Xcode on Mac. 
I tried to remove and add Apple Account in VS and got the same error while logging in when it tries to load certificates. 
Also I checked Polly.dll and it has 7.1.0.0 version updated last month with Xamarin

Comment: Okey , it's strange. If have another apple account , also can have a try whehter it shows. In addition, need to make the Mac also has downloaded provisioning files first . You can check that whether can see the provisoning files in **Keychain Access**.

Comment: Yes, Mac has an Apple Account added and shows certificates in provisioning profile. It is paired to VS successfully. Last month I added Apple Account in VS and it was okay and worked fine.

Comment: Adding another account in VS throws the same error about Polly.dll version. I even reinstalled Xamarin extension. The problem is the same.

Comment: Do you have a try with rebooting PC and Mac to check that ? My local site with the latest version of VS shows well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue. My steps to fix were to update Visual Studio and restart the PC, update XCode to 11.6 (as of 8/6/2020) and restart the Mac. After that I was able to add my developer account to VS(19)! I did not have to reinstall Polly. There were other issues, but not related to this bug.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an issue after update fixed in the next update. So update VS to 16.7.0 and Xamarin.iOS SDK to 13.20.2.2 (Aug 10, 2020) solved the problem.